# difference between lapacke and lapack

Tags: c++, lapack, lapacke

I wonder what is the difference between LAPACK**E** and LAPACK. I want to do Eigen analysis with `QZ` decomposition, but I'm not sure if I should start with LAPACK**E** or LAPACK. I appreciate any help.

Comment: From the Stack Overflow tag descriptions and reading various Google search results and Wikipedia, it looks like LAPACK is a FORTRAN library written in FORTRAN, and LAPACKE is a C wrapper library around the FORTRAN LAPACK library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to use LAPACKE as it frees you from writing helpers for converting from/to row-major mode to column major mode for matrices before/after LAPACK calls.

Answer (score 20):

LAPACKE is the C wrapper for the standard F90 LAPACK library. Honestly, its easier (and more efficient) to do things directly with LAPACK just as long as you store things column-major. LAPACKE ends up calling  (in some fashion) the LAPACK routines anyways.

Comment: That's right. Eventually, I ended up using LAPACKE in my C++ code, because in this way I don't need to be worried about memory allocations. Also, when using LAPACKE, I used the column major option (LAPACK_COL_MAJOR) by storing my arrays in column major fashion, because in this way, LAPACKE consumes less memory (no need for transformation from row major to column major).